# RestApi to get attachment details for a testcase in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to fetch the attachment details and attachment of testcase from VSTS using restapi.

Which restapi from 5.0 to be used to retrieve attachment details?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-5.0

[image]

I have created a PBI added 2 tasks and 2 tests to it as below:

**Is the ID field the WORKITEMID?**

Figure 1:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Case is a work item type, so you can use the [Attachments - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/attachments/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0) REST API.

Downloads an attachment:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments/{id}?api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

To get the `attachment id` you can use the Get Work Item API with `$expand=al`:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all
```

You will get in the results the ID (in the `url` in the `relations` section):

```
"relations":[
     {
       "rel":"AttachedFile",
       "url":"https://shaykia.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/attachments/xxxxx-4453-40b0-acaf-ace14902484c",
```

So now you have the attachment id: `xxxxx-4453-40b0-acaf-ace14902484c`, to download the attachment use the API above (instaed ):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments/xxxxx-4453-40b0-acaf-ace14902484c?api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

Comment: Thank you @shayki for your reply. From where can I fetch attachment ID?

Comment: Is Test Case ID to be passed as WorkItemID?

Comment: I don't sure if I understand the question, please see my update.

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all... For this restapi, is testcase id the workitemID? from where can i find workitemid?

Comment: it's workitem ID, each workitem have ID, open a work item, near the type (Test, Bug, Epic) you will see a number, it's the ID.

Comment: @Amruta did you succeed?

Comment: regarding your screenshots, the ID of the PBI is 20996

Comment: By passing 20996 in https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all... I am getting Unauthorized access error. PAT is used for authorization. Same PAT works for other rest api calls.

Comment: I don't know why :/ is another issue, the rest api it's like I wrote.

Comment: Thank you Shayki... I got it resolved..the api version to be used is 5.0-preview.3 in workitem rest call.  https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all

Comment: @Shayki..is there any restapi from which I can get planid and suiteid details by passing WorkItemId/TestcaseId?

Comment: @Amruta check it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20%20suites/get%20suites%20by%20test%20case%20id?view=vsts-rest-5.0